# Load bulk JSON data into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, json, ssis, sql-server-2014, etl

What is the standard way of loading a bulk of JSON data from a file into a database table in an SQL Server version less than 2016?

I am aware of `OPENJSON()` function that was introduced in SQL Server 2016. However, I am limited to use SQL Server 2014.

The preferable way of doing this is to import data using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS), but there is no in-built connector or a source component to start with.

I tried using [SSIS JSON Component](https://jsonsource.codeplex.com/) for this purpose. Apparently, it is not good from performance point of view.

Is there any other way of bulk loading JSON into SQL?

Comment: My answer to this question should apply here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600180/extract-labels-from-serialized-array-using-sql/37600784#37600784

Comment: I did have a look at the parseJSON function on simple-talk.com, I didn't find it ideal for loading bulk data. I should probably try it out and keep an eye on the performance.

Comment: Phil Factor's parser looked like a T-SQL monster. It might work, but it looked kludge as heck. The main link I referenced is a CRL assembly written by someone who went a step further than Phil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this in **SSIS 2012** / **SQL Server 2012**. The requirement was to consume a RESTful API with various endpoints that returned `json`.

1. In your **Data Flow**, create a **Script Component**. Most likely it will be of **Type = Source** since you will be generating **OutPuts** with **Output Columns** from it.

[image]

2. Create the various OutPuts and OutPut columns for the various fields / data items you will extract from the JSON. Usually this is several tables as shown below.

[image]

3. In the **Scripting Component**'s `CreateNewOutputRows()` override method, Deserialize the JSON data into C# classes. I use http://json2csharp.com/ to stub the classes and then fix it if need in special cases, like if the json has ID values for key, instead of keyname and such. I use **Newtonsoft.Json** to deserialize the json into the class instances / Lists etc. Add rows to the relevant outputbuffer you setup in **Step 2**.
4. Connect the **Outputs** from the **Scripting Component** to the various destination tables.

That's it! You are done.